# BootstrapVue: Creating 2 Navbars with Bottom Navbar that Sticks to the Top?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

What I'm trying to do is create 2 navbars. The first (top navbar) is just a brand (logo). The second (bottom navbar) is a navigation menu. When the user scrolls down, I want the top navbar to scroll off the screen, but I want the 2nd (bottom) navbar to stay fixed at the top of the screen. I've set up each navbar as a separate component.

A good example of this behavior can be found on Reason.com: [link](https://reason.com/2020/03/27/no-british-epidemiologist-neil-ferguson-has-not-drastically-downgraded-his-worst-case-projection-of-covid-19-deaths/)

I'm very confused on how to implement this. I can do:

```
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" class="header" fixed="top">
```

To make the navbar stay at the top of the screen. This works well if I want the 1st navbar to stay at the top but not the 2nd. However, it doesn't work for my situation.

The docs mention [placement](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/navbar) for the navbar. The only other option (other than fixed="top") is to set the div's position to sticky in css:

```
position: sticky
```

However, this only impacts it within the div. Since I have several components, I'm not sure how to implement this properly in Vue since I can't carry over one div from one component to another.

How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was playing with a BootstrapVue codesandbox. I just put

```js
<b-navbar>
....
</b-navbar>

<b-navbar sticky>
....
</b-navbar>
```

and was able to replicate that behaviour.

Edit:

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-vue-sandbox-elhde) if you want to see it.

Comment: Mine is behaving differently, but maybe I just need to set it up differently. I have each of the navbars as a separate component. In app.vue, I have a div with the class "container" that contains all the components. Maybe I should just set it up so the navbars are in app.vue like in your example instead and then work from there.

Comment: OK, now it works. Thanks! Think I just made it overcomplicated by making the navbars separate components. Seeing your template helped a bunch!